# DirectX) Difference between the buffer and texture

Tags: c++, graphics, directx, directx-11

Many people say DirectX has two kinds of resources: **Buffer and Texture**

In the MSDN document, it says that **A buffer is a collection of raw data (elements); a texture is a collection of texels (texture elements)**

But it does not make me really understand. What is clear differences between raw data and texel? Isn't texel can be raw data?

Is there any precise explanation?

Comment: What don't you understand in the article you cite https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d10/d3d10-graphics-programming-guide-resources-types . They both represent "data" but a texel is a specific type of data that can be sampled by shaders

Comment: A main difference between texture resources and buffer resources is that texture resources have a dimension component, so must be configured for either 1D, 2D, or 3D arrays of data. One of the best discussions is found in _Practical Rendering & Computation with Direct3D 11_ by Zink et al (2011).

Comment: This understanding becomes even more important when migrating to DirectX 12, because the **ID3D12Resource** interface alone is used to create both buffer and texture resources. That is, there no longer exist any **ID3D12Buffer** or **ID3D12Texture** equivalents to **ID3D11Buffer**, **ID3D11Texture1D**, **ID3D11Texture2D**, and **ID3D11Texture3D** interfaces found in DirectX 11.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that Textures have specific functionalities available and are load to different registers(t) than buffers. t register have access to additional hardware which makes sampling and filtering faster(a common operation that is performed on textures).

There are also other topics associated with textures like mipmaps, compression, etc which gpu supports them with texture resources.

So if you use these functionalities with your data its better to store it as textures to use the associated hardware.